# AngularJS: how to reload route and rerun $routeProvider resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I let the user select an option which the controller's dependencies depend on,
when the user changes that option, I want to reload the route but also run the resolve section of `$routeProvider`.

`$route.reload()` just reloads the controller, with the same dependencies.

is there a way to do it without refreshing the entire window ?

Comment: I tried $reload.refresh() and the the resolve-Section of my current route was also reevaluated. Angular Version is 1.2.8

Answer (score 0):

Update your location to the same route but with a different parameter value with `$location.path()` or `$location.search()`